# Xamarin Forms Multiple list items on same index of carousel view c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am using xamarin carousel view. Salon is my parent list and SalonService is called as features in each Salon list item.

My code displays only one item per view. I want to display three (3) items on each carousel view.

Below is my code for lists:

```
Ftrs.Add(new SalonService() { Services = "Test 1", Prices = "$150" });
Ftrs.Add(new SalonService() { Services = "Test 2", Prices = "$150" });
Ftrs.Add(new SalonService() { Services = "Test 3", Prices = "$150" });
Ftrs.Add(new SalonService() { Services = "Test 4", Prices = "$150" });

salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 1", Features = Ftrs });
salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 2", Features = Ftrs });
salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 3", Features = Ftrs });
salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 4", Features = Ftrs });
salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 5", Features = Ftrs });
salons.Add(new Salon() { ImgUrl = "test.png", Title = "Test Title 6", Features = Ftrs });
```

Below is my code for carousel view:

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
 DataTemplate salonDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
 {
    // some code
 });

Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
Resources.Add("salonTemplate", salonDataTemplate);

int countIndex = 1;
int newPageCount = 1;

foreach (var newItem in item.Features)
{
    if (newPageCount <= 3)
    {
        //same carousal view
    }
    else
    {
        countIndex++;
        //new carousal view
    }
    newPageCount++;
} }

var list_Featured = new CarouselView()
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
    //ItemsSource = item.Features,
    ItemsSource = newList,
        ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["salonTemplate"], HeightRequest = 150 
};

StackLayout stkList = new StackLayout();
stkList.IsVisible = false;
stkList.Children.Add(list_Featured);
```

Current Output:

- Test Title 1
- Test 1

Expected Output:

- Test Title 1
- Test 1
- Test 2
- Test 3

My carousel view is only displaying one item per view. I want to display three items per view.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm missing what your exact problem is. Where does it go wrong? What did you expect? Do you have any clues? Please refer to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to read up on how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: My carousel view is only displaying one item per view. I want to display three items per view.

Comment: Can you please show your xaml code? What is the template for carouselview's item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my desired result by creating a list of lists.

Something like this:

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
myList.Add(new List<string> { "a", "b" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "c", "d", "e" });
```